# Matplotlib X-Axis Labels are cut off although using tight_layout

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` and the labels on the x-Axis are cut off. I tried different things:

1. rotating the labels
2. Using `plt.tight_layout()`
3. Using `pylab.rcParams.update(params)` and setting `'xtick.labelsize':'small'`

But none of them helped and I have still the problem. See the pictures:

[image]
As you can see, only part of the date is shown in the x-axis. Instead of `2018-11-19 11:00` it is shown `11-29 11`. How can I solve that?

Comment: The labels are not cut. They are simply in the format `month-day hour` instead of `year-month-day hour:minute`. You can use a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` formatter to get the format you like.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's weird, because if I select a wider range of date, then `year-month-day` is shown.

Comment: Sure, matplotlib decides upon a useful format automatically depending on a range of data. It wouldn't make sense to show milliseconds on a plot that covers a whole century, right?